# What is voltage level in DDR5 defined by JEDEC?

Tags: memory, ddr, ddr3

Voltage level in DDR4 is 1.2 volt, will it be same in DRR5 also? Also how much maximum voltage fluctuation will be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR5_SDRAM):

> Compared to DDR4, DDR5 further reduces memory module voltage to 1.1 V, thus reducing power consumption. DDR5 modules incorporate on board voltage regulators, thus making voltage regulators for RAM on motherboards unnecessary.